# update winform c# from another form after adding buttons dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a prototype project in c# WinForms, that has 3 forms as follows:

[image]

[1-MasterForm
2-Layout
3-UpdateLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ROK1.png)
i also have a table in my database, that table simply have 2 column one for the layout_no, another for layout_status. if the layout is busy i need to change its color to red, if not busy i keep it to green color.

Ny problem after I update the layout to busy is, that it doesn't refresh in the `MasterForm`.

Here's my code for `UpdateLayout` Form:

```
public void refreshLayout()
{
    try
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectToDB))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT layout_no, is_busy FROM layout_table", con))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                int totalrows = dt.Rows.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < totalrows; i++)
                {
                    int status = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["is_busy"]);
                    Button ButtonAllLayout = new Button();
                    ButtonAllLayout.Name = "Layout'" + (i + 1) + "'";
                    ButtonAllLayout.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Layout_no"].ToString();
                    styleButton();//apply the button location...etc
                    this.Controls.Add(ButtonAllLayout);
                    if (status == 1)
                    {
                        ButtonAllLayout.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ButtonAllLayout.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    refreshLayout();
}
```

Here's my code for `MasterForm`:

```
public MasterForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void BtnLayout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Layout l1 = new Layout();
    l1.refreshLayout();
    splitContainerMain.Panel2.Show();
    splitContainerMain.Panel2.Controls.Add(l1);
    l1.Show();
}

private void BtnSetting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Settings s1 = new Layout();
    splitContainerMain.Panel2.Show();
    splitContainerMain.Panel2.Controls.Add(s1);
    s1.Show();
}

private void BtnMain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Main m1 = new Main();
    splitContainerMain.Panel2.Show();
    splitContainerMain.Panel2.Controls.Add(m1);
    m1.Show();
}
```

Can you please guide me how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Is the `status` *definitely* updating from your DB? An aside note: is there any particular reason you're just re-throwing the exception without doing anything else? Have a read-up on handling exceptions :)

Comment: What is the point of doing `catch (Exception) { throw; }`?

Comment: What I said @Enigmativity ^^ :D

Comment: @GeoffJames - Yep, that. Sorry to repeat.

Comment: @Enigmativity Haha, it's cool. We good :p

Comment: remember to finish with **this.PerformLayout();** to apply the updates to the winform

Comment: guys... i am just trying to simulate my problem for you , please guide me in the mentioned problem...thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First you should give the parent info for UpdateLayout forms

```
UpdateLayout frm = new UpdateLayout();
frm.Owner = this; //Layout form
frm.Show();
```

After that you can call public refreshLayout method of Layout form,

from UpdateLayout form's button event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (this.Owner as UpdateLayout).refreshLayout();
}
```

Also you need to clear buttons previously created

at the begining of refreshLayout method

```
this.Controls.Clear();
```

Or implement new method other than refreshLayout to change only changed button's backColor

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see your buttons are all added with Size(0,0) and Location(0,0). So I think they are there but simply not visible because of size and location.

Try to add something like this:

```
int startX = 0;
int startY = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < totalrows; i++)
{
    int status = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["is_busy"]);
    Button ButtonAllLayout = new Button();
    ButtonAllLayout.Name = "Layout'" + (i + 1) + "'";
    ButtonAllLayout.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Layout_no"].ToString();
    ButtonAllLayout.Size = new Size(80, 20);
    ButtonAllLayout.Location = new Point(startX, startY);
    startY += 23;
    this.Controls.Add(ButtonAllLayout);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.... the issue not with the location, i have set the location and everything works great if i am clicking the layout button from the MasterForm, but when i try to invoke the same code from UpdateLayout it doesn't refresh and doesn

Comment: Wouldn't the button's size be automatic, if it's not set, anyway?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.... the issue not with the location, i have set the location and everything works great if i am clicking the layout button from the MasterForm, but when i try to invoke the same code from UpdateLayout it doesn't refresh and doesn't load correctly until i click again on the Layout button from MasterForm

Comment: But you add the buttons always to your UpdateLayout, not to the MasterForm: this.Controls.Add(...) while this is your UpdateLayout-Form.

Comment: may you please have a look at the image that i attached ?

Comment: there are 3 forms, the drawing done in Layout form, i corrected my code accordingly, my issue only when i click update layout button it doesn't do any changes but when i click on the Layout button from the MasterForm it works perfectly

Comment: I saw it. But as I wrote: You allways add the buttons to the UpdateForm object. Your code 'this.Controls.Add(...)' is very clear at this point (because if 'refreshlayout' is really a method of your UpdateLayoutForm). Maybe you should post your COMPLETE sourcecode to make this more clear. It looks to me that ther are much more things going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

To apply custom `BackColor` to your button you should set `UseVisualStyleBackColor = false` for your `ButtonAllLayout`.

By the way, in production code, it's not a good idea to open DB connection on GUI thread.